# Unsupervised Anomaly Detection on system metrics like memory, cpu, io, net, etc

Tags: unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

In all the examples that I can see online, people have used a labelled dataset. I however am stuck trying to construct a model to perform anomaly detection on unlabelled dataset (unsupervised anomaly detection).

> Problem Statement: To separate the anomalous points from the normal ones. The features available with us are mem_usage, mem_total, cpu_usage_idle, cpu_usage_iowait, etc

Using the anomaly detection, I plan to label the dataset saying whether anomalous or not. A step further would be aggregate each row based on the server the data belongs to and find if the server is healthy, problematic. Even further would be predicting when a server might face a similar problem and thus suggest ways to mitigate the problem.

Any kind of resources (papers, code blogs, videos) are really welcome. I am just starting out and am open to trying out new stuff as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have sequence data about these metrics? E.g. do they evolve over time and you want to locate anomalies in these sequences?

If so, you can have a look at the tools described here:

> https://github.com/rob-med/awesome-TS-anomaly-detection

They are all unsupervised methods, so you don't need anomaly-free data for training.

If you are not dealing with time-series, there are also many unsupervised approaches you can take. This paper offers a good survey on the topic

> https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0152173

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@curiousily/credit-card-fraud-detection-using-autoencoders-in-keras-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-vii-20e0c85301bd

> In this part of the series, we will train an Autoencoder Neural
>   Network (implemented in Keras) in unsupervised (or semi-supervised)
>   fashion for Anomaly Detection in credit card transaction data. The
>   trained model will be evaluated on pre-labeled and anonymized dataset.

Comment: Nice post. However it uses the fact that labels are known before hand, and trains the auto-encoder only on *normal* instances. OP data-set has no label, in fact OP wants to label the data set.

Comment: Yes. There is a bias towards using labelled dataset. Imagine a case where there are no labels. If there is any implementation for such a case, would be happy to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer "Isolation Forest based Anomaly Detection". I think it will help. Reference: Liu et al.,2008. It is an unsupervised anomaly detection.

Comment: I have been working on it. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the Isolation Forest Algorithm to identify the anomaly points. You can take a look..
https://github.com/muratyldrim/CatchME

Comment: Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/83524)